# Image of a linear transformation notation

Tags: linear-algebra

I am a first year applied physics student and in the dictate they use the following notation ?to represent an image of a linear transformation?:

$$T: \mathbb{R} ^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} ^{k}$$

I don't quite understand this notation because if $n \neq k$ then it is not a bijective function, is it? Or does this not have to be true? The way for representing an image of a linear transformation is also not quite clear to me.

Comment: Did you intend to write $\mathbb{R}$ instead of $\mathcal{R}$?

Comment: @AnotherUser Yes, I did! Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: The notation $T:\mathbb{R}^n\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^k$ denotes the linear map $T$, not its image.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Linear transformations need not be bijective.

In general, we can represent a function (any function, between any structures, linear or not) by denoting it by $$f: X \to Y$$ where this means the function $f$ takes elements of $X$ and maps them to elements of $Y.$ We call $X$ the domain and $Y$ the codomain.

What you have above is just "declaring" the source and target of the function. It doesn't give an explicit rule. It takes vectors from $\mathbb{R}^n$ and maps them to $\mathbb{R}^k$ by some yet-to-be-determined rule.

As an example, the function $T: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ defined by the rule $T(x, y) = (-x, y)$ takes points in the plane and maps it to another point in the plane. Another example: the function $T: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$ takes vectors in three-dimensional space and maps it to a real number - but notice I didn't define a rule for it! I just told you what the function eats and what it spits out.

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation! So the *linear map* $T: \mathbb{R} ^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ can be seen as a ?"recipe"? which takes in three inputs $x_1, x_2, x_3$ and outputs a single value? Can this be interpreted geometrically?

Comment: you've already answered the geometrical interpretation, sorry. The linear map represents a projection of three-dimensional space onto a one-dimensional space.

Comment: Careful! I never said those maps $T$ were linear.

Answer (score 0):

- a linear map does not need to be bijective, if it is then it's called an isomorphism.
- the notation you gave simply means that Γ is a function from the vector space $\mathbb{R} ^{n}$ (as a domain) to $\mathbb{R} ^{k}$ (as a codomain) and it does not imply that Γ is linear.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Ah clear, thank you. $T$ is linear if $T( \vec{u} + \vec{v} ) = T( \vec{u} ) + T( \vec{v} ) $ and $T( c \vec{u} ) =c T( \vec{u})$ right?

Comment: @Masterrun80 yes exactly, so you need to verify that the function you have satisfies those two conditions to call it linear